# Batch that copy and paste a folder with some rules

Tags: windows, batch-file

--------------REFORMULATION---------------

When I start a new project I have to copy and paste a "model folder" that contains all I need. The name of this folder is IT.16.XXXX and all I do is change the number of it (example: IT.16.9555, IT.16.9654 and so on) and add some words after that number (exemple: IT.16.9555_Office in London).

I want to automatize that process.

In order to do that I want that the batch recognize what is the last project number and ask me for a sentence to add in the folder name.

---

EDIT 10/062016
Hello guys, I've found a solution but i need some help to make a little change.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
cd /d C:\Users\Dennis\Desktop\Test\
set I=1
:NextI
if /I %I% LEQ 999 set II=0%I%
if /I %I% LEQ 99 set II=00%I%
if /I %I% LEQ 9 set II=000%I%

if not exist "IT.16.!II!*" (
set /p "client_name=OPZIONALE Informazioni aggiuntive <INVIO>: "
xcopy /s /e /i "IT.16.XXXX_" "IT.16.!II!_!client_name!"
goto :eof
)

set /a I+=1
if /i %I% LSS 999 goto NextI
```

The problem is that my template model is in C:\Users\Dennis\Desktop\Test\ and the folder I want to create is in a subfolder C:\Users\Dennis\Desktop\Test\1_TEST

Any advice? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very baffling. Someone needs to edit it. Though I have a pertial answer.

Yes you can ask take input with a prompt.

```
set /p nam=Insert_the_name:
echo "Your folder name is %nam%"
```

This will store the user input to `nam`.

Comment: Thats ok but can you please try to edit and improve your question?

Comment: it's ok now? I've found a partial solution that can help people to understand what I mean